# AWS EC2 Launch Template user-data don't work

Tags: amazon-ec2, ec2-userdata

I try to launch EC2 instance with a simple user-data set:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo su -
sudo yum -y update
sudo yum install -y docker
sudo service docker start
sudo usermod -aG docker ec2-user

docker pull yeasy/simple-web
docker run -d --rm -it -p 80:80 yeasy/simple-web:latest
```

But it just doesn't seem to be working. Even when I try to put this command in .sh script an already InService EC2 instance, it still doesn't work.

However, if I run all manually, it is okay.

SG is configured properly as well as NACL.

What can be the problem or how it is possible to troubleshoot?

**UPD**

I've replaced user-data with:

```
#!/bin/bash

dnf install docker -y
systemctl enable docker
systemctl start docker

docker pull yeasy/simple-web
docker run -d --rm -it -p 80:80 yeasy/simple-web:latest
```

And it works. But still wonder what was the problem with first version?